# Can't get jquery function to work on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My jquery function works fine on local, but once I add it to my WP footer and upload, nothing.

There are a lot of scripts on this page, the but the script I'm trying to make work is this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("li.accordion").on('click',function() {
    $('.mega-sub-menu', this).slideToggle("fast", function() {});
  });
});
```

Jquery is loaded and working, but this script won't function.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Thanks, but it wasn't the stray '

I seemed to be having a cache issue on the site, which has been updated now. Still having the problem.

EDIT2: Removed a link

Comment: do you have any `<li>` with class including `accordion` .. do these `<li>` have a child element with class including `mega-sub-menu`? Are there any errors in the developer tools console when loading your site - i.e. the stray `'` on line 2138 is probably the problem - also, when you fix that, you actually use, in your code, `jQuery` not `$` ... but you also use `jquery` which isn't `jQuery` because `q` isn't `Q`

Comment: I have an error but nothing related to this. Everything works locally — I copied the menu straight from the dev site, so it's exactly the same structure locally as it is online. Looks like you might be getting served a cached version. I'll see if I can clear it

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready()`.... should be replaced with `jQuery(function($){...`, you will be getting a deprecated function warnings.

Comment: seriously, the `'` on line 2138 is the issue

Comment: I wish! There was a cache error … I've updated the code several times now and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site has a syntax error on it.  There is a quote at the end of your JavaScript which may well be causing it to not execute.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jquery("li.accordion").click(function() {
        jquery('.mega-sub-menu', this).slideToggle("fast", function() {});
    });
});' <--- quote here
```

Ok, you've fixed that now, and all the JavaScript is working, but I can see the next issue that prevents the menu from showing is a CSS rule with !important. (It's overriding the style="display:block" attribute on the mega-sub-menu that is added via JQuery).

[image: mega-sub-menu]

Comment: Yeah, and I've fixed that but now of course I'm having a caching error of some sort

Comment: yeah you're right! That's it! Thanks. I had that for a valid reason, I swear but it looks like it cased a conflict with the rest of the CSS on the site. Now my question is — how do I have that accordion start CLOSED?

Comment: You could put style="display:none" on it.  Or make a CSS rule that is more specific than all those other ones and kill the !important.  In any case I suggest marking this as accepted answer and asking a new question if neither of those work for you.

Comment: @Tomasch as a rule of thumb, if you're having to use `!important` in CSS it most likely means you have done something wrong elsewhere. Don't underestimate the importance of having maintainable and predictable CSS.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing a little more googling, I came up with this answer:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('li.accordion').click(function() {
             $('.mega-sub-menu', this).slideToggle('fast', function() {});
    }).click();

});
```

Here we simulate the click so that the accordion starts out closed and I don't need to add any more CSS to anything.

I added important to the CSS earlier to overcome the inline style — like an idiot, not realizing that the jquery was adding the inline style (I think that's what I did anyway, it was inappropriately late.)

Comment: That's an answer to a different question than you asked.  Given I spent 15 minutes finding out what your problem was you could at least upvote it, if not tick it as the accepted answer.